# C programming: How to read and add up a file

Tags: c

For C programming how do i make a while or for loop to read a file then add the numbers together and make an average? using only the libraries <math.h> and <stdio.h> Im very new to C so please add notes!

tried to use `while (fscanf(fin,"%", &x) !=EOF){ x++}`
but im not sure how to make it read the values.
full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MXN 100

int main(void) {
    int n = 0;
    float avg, x;
      
    float scores[MXN];
     
    FILE * fin = fopen("values.txt", "r");
    while (fscanf(fin, "%f", &scores[n]) != EOF) {
        n++;  
    } 

    while (fscanf(fin, "%f", &x) != EOF) {
        x++;
    }
       
    avg = x/n;
    
    printf(" the array size is %d and the average of numbers read from the file is %f", n, avg);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the first while loop reads to the end of the file, what do you expect the second while loop to do?

Comment: First -- why on earth would you need `math.h` to computer an average? Only include headers that provide a function or define used by your code. You only need `math.h` when you include math functions (like `cos()`, `sin()`, `fabs()`, etc...) If you are unsure, check the *man-page*. Cryptic at first, but man pages provide concise information on exactly how to use each function (with the header required specified at the top `:)`, e.g. [man 3 cos](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/cos.3.html)

Comment: What would be the purpose of `x++;` in that loop? Immediately afterwards you try to read another value from the file into this variable overwriting whatever you had stored there before.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to save the numbers in an array. Just add them on the fly. Like:

```
avg = 0;
while (fscanf(fin, "%f", &x) == 1){
    n++;
    avg = avg + x;  // or avg += x;
}
if (n > 0) {     // Avoid division by zero
    avg = avg/n;
}
```

Also notice that it's better to check the `fscanf` return value using `== 1` instead of `!= EOF` as use of `!= EOF` may result in an endless loop if a file contains something that isn't a float value.

If you for some reason prefer to read into an array,  your code could be something like:

```
while (n < MXN && fscanf(fin, "%f", &scores[n]) == 1) {
    n++;  
} 

avg = 0;
for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
    avg = avg + scores[i];   // or avg += scores[i];
}
if (n > 0) {     // Avoid division by zero
    avg = avg/n;
}
```

Comment: Don't know where the heck all the `!= EOF` return checks have come from lately, good job hammering the fact that is wrong and that proper comparison is the *match count* which will identify a *matching failure* instead of `EOF` catching only *input failures*...

Comment: There may be an error here. You're summing up into `avg` but then dividing `sum` by `n`.

Comment: @Chris Thanks... I first used a `sum` variable to hold the "on the fly" result but then I realized an extra variable wasn't needed and did an edit to remove it. But my edit  was incomplete :-(  Thanks for pointing that out.